# How to reduce white space margins of world map

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, r-maptools

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl)
box()
```

This gives me a world map and shows the plentiful white space top and bottom of the map. I would like this space to be gone as I need to print many (~60) maps. I am using `knitr` for the report in which the maps will be embedded. E.g.

```
Here is some text.
<<chunk.maps, eval = TRUE>>=
library(maptools)
plot(wrld_simpl)
box()
@
And some more text.
```

But I don't think this is a `knitr` question. So:

1. How can I get rid of the white space?
2. How can I make sure that the map fills my page from left to right?

I have tried `mai`, `mar`, `par`, but no such luck! I am guessing `out.width` for the chunk option will give the result for my question 2, but since I am so badly stuck on question 1 I find it hard to tell.

Thank you very much! There is so much to learn out here!

Comment: have you tried inserting `par(mar=rep(0,4))` before the call to `plot`? I can't check it with knitr/latex at the moment, but it gets rid of the white space in many R graphics devices.

Comment: Calling `par(...)` before or after calling `plot` doesn't do the trick, unfortunately. Thank you though. It was worth a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `ggplot2` for these kinds of maps:

```
require(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
wrld_simpl_df = fortify(wrld_simpl)
ggplot(wrld_simpl_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
   geom_path() + coord_equal()
```

[image]

This also includes the whitespace you where complaining about. The problem is that the aspect ratio between the x- and y-axis is fixed. So if you choose a square graphics device, that will leave white borders above and below. The solution is to make your graphics device have roughly the same proportions as your plot. Use `fig.width` and  `fig.height` to do this. See [this link](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) for more info. As an illustration, when saving the plot above with the correct proportions:

```
ggsave("/tmp/plt.png", width = 16, height = 9)
```

[image]

the problem is no longer present.

Comment: With `fig.height` and `fig.width` alone in the chunk options I could change the shape of the graphs. This is what I want. Great! At first my title and legend had been too small, but I fixed that with `par(cex=2)`. Thank you! (And I didn't need to dive into yet another new package for me, i.e. `ggplot2` -phew!)

Comment: yes, you need to be careful with the dimension of the plot when you draw maps (e.g. need to set appropriate `fig.height` and `fig.width` so the map fills in the white space); the other approach is to simply leave it alone and crop the plots afterwards (see the [graphics manual](https://github.com/downloads/yihui/knitr/knitr-graphics.pdf) for cropping images)

Comment: @Yihui Thank you, I appreciate your contribution. Now that I checked the graphics manual again I remember that I actually tried to follow your instructions, but failed. (I agree that I should have mentioned that, too.) I could try again, if it helps the community when I post the error message. I would open up a new post for it though. Let me know.