# align ggplot map plots with coord_equal()

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, cowplot

I am having trouble aligning two maps. I am using a reproducible example below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
world <- map_data("world")

pl2= ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  theme_bw()+
  coord_equal()
pl1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, color=group)) +
  coord_equal()
plot_grid(pl2, pl1 + theme(legend.justification = c(0,1)), align="h",axis = "bt")
```

I tried various things like setting the figure widths and heights, trying `scale=`,various options from `align="h",axis = "bt"`
I also tried `plot_grid(pl2, pl1+ theme(legend.position = "none"), align="h", scale=c(1,1))` and then add `legend legend <- get_legend(pl1)` with `plot_grid` again.
I also have a crazy amount of white space when I use coord_equal, that I can't get rid of ( I am not saving the graph, just displaying it)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer using the `patchwork` package for aligning plots, simple framework (with lots of additional functionality), and out of the box does what you want here.

```r
library(patchwork)
pl2 + pl1
```

[image]

Comment: In terms of white space on the world map, I believe it's a [graphics device issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343726/how-to-reduce-white-space-margins-of-world-map).

Comment: @caldwest, yep, indeed! I set the ratio width:length 1:4 and white space dissapear